# Windows 7 lag after installing 208 updates

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, lag

I recently did a clean install of windows 7 x64 ultimate, and after the install, everything was fine, so I proceeded to download the 208 updates windows recommended. After I restarted the computer, windows is extremely laggy and unresponsive, however, prefmon says 0% disk, 0% cpu usage, and I can't find any program that could be causing this. The cursor doesn't lagg at all, but the entire UI takes about three seconds to update anything.

Starting windows in safe mode works fine.
System specs:

```
Cpu: Intel Core i3 530 (2,93GHz, 3 MB cache)
chipset: Intel H55
RAM: 2 GB DDR-III 1333 MHz
SSD: ocz agility 4 120GB SATA
```

Comment: update your RAM. 2GB is not enough for 64Bit windows

Comment: @magicandre1981 actually, after further trials and testing, I found that this is related to the intel graphics driver. However, I still haven't found a solution.

Comment: reduce the size of the GPU in BIOS. if the value is too high the intel driver leaks memory.  but again, 2GB is not enough for 64Bit Windows. Get at least 4 GB RAM.

Comment: @magicandre1981 video calling on skype crashes the driver. After that, everything is fine. No memory problems, no lag problems, everything is perfectly fine.

Comment: this is no real fix, only a strange workaround. install more RAM and also try to get a newer GPU driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after I realized that this was a driver issue, I tried many different drivers, but finally, [video graphics driver version 8.15.10.2622](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/21480/Graphics-Intel-HD-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-Vista-and-Windows-7-), contrary to [magicandre1981's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1193185/windows-7-lag-after-installing-208-updates?noredirect=1#comment1734828_1193185) solved this issue.

Also, for the unmediated, 2GB RAM is the [official system requirement](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10737/windows-7-system-requirements) of windows 7 64bit.

> If you want to run Windows 7 on your PC, here's what it takes:
>
> - 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor*
> - 1 gigabyte (GB) RAM (32-bit) or **2 GB RAM (64-bit)**
> - 16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
> - DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: again, this is the minimum . I have 2GB for 32bit win10 and it still not enough

Comment: Of course it's undeniable, that 2GB is not much. However I was trying to stress that RAM is out of the scope of this question, as this machine has been fine for years with 2GB of ram and windows 7 64bit.